# open a executable file with crontab and show it on monitor

Tags: command-line

my question is:
I have a c++ file (compiled file), and I make cron job that can do a bash script. in this command, it should open this c++ file, but crontab could not open the file and show it on monitor. how can I fix it??
plz help me with some code.
I use ubuntu 19.10
.
thank everybody who spend a little time.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see the contents of a compiled file, have cron kick off a hex editor with the compiled file name as a parameter. A few [are listed here](https://itsfoss.com/hex-editors-linux/) in no particular order, such as the [GNOME Hex Editor](https://github.com/GNOME/ghex/blob/mainline/README).

Comment: I have trouble with opening the site. if it can happen plz help me with some bash code.

Comment: See above second link